# unity c# - how to get multiple things in one element of an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an array that looks like this image but cannot work out how to get for example a gameobject and an int into one element of an array.

[image]

Comment: well wrap them in a type ... `[Serializable] public class ValuePair { public GameObject item; public int quantity; }` and then `public ValuePair[] requirements;` => tadaaa? ... maybe worth looking some very basic tutorials about c# in general first? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining a custom class or struct containing multiple [serialized fields](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) and adding the [Serializable attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html) to it.

```
[Serializable]
public class ElementData
{
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public int amount;
}
```

Then you can define an array of this custom class.

```
public ElementData[] array;
```